# VS code c++ for macOS: compilation works but VS code detects errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c++17

I followed the tutorial on this webpage: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac to be able to compile c++ programs using VS Code. After doing all things requested, I am able to compile and to debug the c++ file.

However, it seems that there is an issue. In the box "PROBLEMS", I have the two following errors:

> expected ';' at end of declaration [9, 23]
>
> range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions] [11,
> 29]

My code is exactly the same as the one reported in the VS code website. I also checked all *.json files and c++17 is the default compiler.

The tasks.json is as follows:

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
  {
    "type": "shell",
    "label": "clang++ build active file",
    "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
    "args": [
      "-std=c++17",
      "-stdlib=libc++",
      "-g",
      "${file}",
      "-o",
      "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
    ],
    "options": {
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
    "group": {
      "kind": "build",
      "isDefault": true
    }
  }
]
```

}

The c_cpp_properties.json is as follows:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "macFrameworkPath": [
            "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

When compiling, everything is fine:

```
> Executing task: /usr/bin/clang++ -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -g /Users/stephane/Documents/c++/causality/run_mainfile.cpp -o /Users/stephane/Documents/c++/causality/run_mainfile <
Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I am using macOS 10.15.6, VS Code 1.47.1, and C/C++ extension v0.29.

Any ideas?

Comment: It sure sounds like you're not actually running a compiler in C++17 mode. Show the full build setup and resulting command lines in the question.

Comment: Did you install the Intellisens or a similar plugin that adds auto-completion and syntax checking while you type? It might be that this tool uses different settings then your compiler and as of that reports different errors.

Comment: I installed C++ extension for VS Code, including IntelliSense. I now also report some *.json files.

Comment: @RangerBob Your configuration files look fine to me. Try restarting VSCode and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @brc-dd I did, but it does not change anything.

Comment: @RangerBob Can you add screenshots showing warning/error and the code to the question? Also, please mention the version of extension(s) you are using along with VS code's version (from Help > About).

Comment: @brc-dd So now you have screenshot showing the errors and the code. I also added that I am using VS Code 1.47.1, and C/C++ extension v0.29.

Comment: @RangerBob Nothing proper is hitting to me right now. Everything seems to be fine with the configuration. There is one thing you can try:  Create a new directory. Open it with vscode, then open preferences > search > "c++ standard". Choose C++17 or C++20, whichever is available. Do nothing else. Create your file and check if problem persists. I know this is not "a solution", though you can give it a try, it won't cause much harm. If it persists then raise an issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues.

Answer (score 2):

@RangerBob The solution is simply what @brc-dd said but you don't have to create a new project/directory. Go to Preferences > Search > "c++ standard". Choose C++17, and VS Code will create a new file "settings.json" with that standard causing the 3 warnings to disappear.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've been trying to fix this issue for many hours and this has worked. Thank you very much!